# C# JSON to String with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, json, office365, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an UWP App in Visual Studio 2017 and I want to convert a JSON-Response from Office365 REST API into a string, to Display it in the XAML.

```
HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
var token2 = await AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenHelperAsync();
client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
HttpResponseMessage eventresponse = await client2.GetAsync(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2017-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2017-04-05T12:00:00"));
```

I can't get json.net, i guess it is not compatible. 
I tried the following:

```
using (Stream stream = eventresponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But I can't convert HttpResponseMessage into System.IO.Stream.

JavaScriptSerializer is not available for UWP Apps as it seems.

DataContractJsonSerializer can't convert to char aswell.

So im running out of possible Solutions/overseeing a big mistake I made.

Comment: `await eventresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

Comment: What do you mean JSON.NET isn't compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
using (Stream stream = eventresponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

to

```
string responseString = await eventresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Or with stream like your code..

```
if (eventresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (Stream stream = await eventresponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the `HttpResponseMessage` is concerned, the response body is a series of bytes.  It is indifferent to what they actually represent.

You can access these bytes through the [`Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content(v=vs.118).aspx) member and use methods on that member to direct how they the bytes should be processed ([including accessing them as a Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync(v=vs.118).aspx)).

In your case you indicate you want a string, so you could use [`ReadAsStringAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need GetResponse....

```
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
txtBlock.Text = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```